# How to visualize the visual words from a bag of features classifier in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, object-recognition

I am using bag of features to classify histology images in MATLAB.

here is the code that I used. It's taken from the `imageCategoryClassificationExample

Location of the compressed data set

```
url=http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/101_ObjectCategories.tar.gz';
```

Store the output in a temporary folder

```
outputFolder = fullfile(tempdir, 'caltech101');

rootFolder = fullfile(outputFolder, '101_ObjectCategories');
imgSets = [ imageSet(fullfile(rootFolder, 'airplanes')), ...
            imageSet(fullfile(rootFolder, 'ferry')), ...
            imageSet(fullfile(rootFolder, 'laptop')) ];
```

determine the smallest amount of images in a category

```
minSetCount = min([imgSets.Count]);
```

Use `partition` method to trim the set.

```
imgSets = partition(imgSets, minSetCount, 'randomize');
```

Separate the sets into training and validation data.

```
[trainingSets, validationSets] = partition(imgSets, 0.3, 'randomize');
```

Create the bag of features classifier

```
bag = bagOfFeatures(trainingSets);
```

Additionally, the `bagOfFeatures` object provides an `encode` method for
counting the visual word occurrences in an image. It produced a histogram
that becomes a new and reduced representation of an image.

```
img = read(imgSets(1), 1);
[featureVector,words] = encode(bag, img);
```

Plot the histogram of visual word occurrences

```
figure
bar(featureVector)
title('Visual word occurrences')
xlabel('Visual word index')
ylabel('Frequency of occurrence')
```

After the creation of the bag of features object how can I visualize the final codebook and which visual words make up each image? Can I reconstruct the image from these words? I think it has to do with the use of `encode` to create a `visualWords` object. But how do I proceed after that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function in MATLAB that would do that for you. However there are [papers](http://user.keio.ac.jp/~yun/projects/explore/vinci2014.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: Can you give me an example of those papers?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. By the way, all you have to do is google "visualizing bag of features".